# Multiple conditions in the ternary operator safe?

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have seen advice that says the ternary operator must not be nested.

I have tested the code below and it works okay. My question is, I haven't seen the ternary operator used like this before. So, is this as reliable as it were used in an `if` or could something like this come and bite me later(not in terms or readability, but by failing).

```
$rule1 = true;
$rule2 = false;
$rule3 = true;

$res = (($rule1 == true) && ($rule2 == false) && ($rule3 == true)) ? true : false;

if($res) {
    echo "good";        
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Actually you don't need the `? true : false` part... You'd basically be doing something similar to `true ? true : false` which is redundant.

Comment: nothing wrong here - good to go

Comment: @Gordon: Isn't stacking doing something like `(condition) ? true : (condition) ? true : false`?

Comment: animuson and gordon are both on point for this - if you want a code cleanup see below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the results you are returning from the ternary operator are only "true" and "false", then you don't even need the operator. You can just have:

```
$res = (($rule1 === true) && ($rule2 === false) && ($rule3 === true))
```

But, to answer your question, yes multiple conditions work perfectly well.

Comment: You don't even need the `=== true` and `=== false` parts either (OP's question doesn't use strict comparison).

Answer (score 10):

It's totally legal, it works and is "as reliable as if", but it looks ugly.

If you put each ternary statement inside parenthesis, nesting would be fine too:

```
$res = ( $rule1 ? true : ( $rule2 ? true : false ) )
```

The only thing that is advised against in the manual is nesting without parenthesis like this:

```
$res = ( $rule1 ? true : $rule2 ? true : false )
```

Comment: ooh, I hate scanning nested ternaries, even in parentheses. Avoid IMO :)

Comment: @webbie Agreed, my "it looks ugly" remark should actually translate to "avoid" :) but it is a perfectly valid statement.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you want to have your conditions saved into a variable? this is the simplified version of above.

```
if($rule1 && !$rule2 && $rule3)
{
    echo "good";
}
else
{
    echo "bad";
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Unless he's using that boolean value again later on, just putting it into an If is better and doesn't assign a useless variable that's never used again.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the ternary if you are going to return `true` or `false`. [Quoting the manual:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

> The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.

This means

```
$res = (($rule1 == true) && ($rule2 == false) && ($rule3 == true));
```

will assign true or false already. Also, if dont care about $rule being booleans, you dont need the comparison with `==`. You also dont need the braces, e.g.

```
$res = $rule1 && !$rule2 && $rule3;
```

is the same as your initial ternary.

A good practise when you have multiple expressions like that is to hide the actual comparison behind a meaningful method or function name, e.g.

```
function conditionsMet($rule1, $rule2, $rule3) {
    return $rule1 && !$rule2 && $rule3;
}
```

and then you can do

```
if (conditionsMet($rule1, $rule2, $rule3)) {
    // do something
}
```

Of course, `conditionsMet` isnt *that* meaningful. A better example would be something like `isSummerTime` or `isEligibleForDiscount` and so on. Just express what the rules express in the method name.

You might also be interested in [Simplifying Conditional Expressions](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/simplifying-conditional-expressions) from the book [Refactoring - Improving the design of existing code](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoring).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
 $res = ($rule1 && !$rule2 && $rule3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's legal and doesn't have to be "ugly". I use the "hook" operator often, in table form it's quite clean, e.g.:

```
bool haveANeed() 
{ 
    //     Condition       result
    //     ----------      ------
    return needToEat()   ? true
         : needToSleep() ? true
         : needToStudy() ? true
         : needToShop()  ? true
         : needToThink() ? true
         :                 false; // no needs!
}
```

This function would, IMHO, be less clear and certainly longer if written with if-else logic.

Comment: `return needToEat() || needToSleep() || needToStudy() || needToShop() || needToThink();` is shorter and clearer.

Comment: You are correct. I was just trying to emphasize the table-like neatness of using the ternary operator.